# word (Not line) difference between two text file

Tags: python, shell

I am having two text file file_1 and file_2

file_1:

social media is the most commonly used **application** on internet where
people **discuss** and **share** their emotions with **community** **twitter** 
**popular** social media applications and **has** **witnessed** **a wider reach** social
**popularly** **used** in the political campaign across **world researchers** have
**for** **various** political **campaigns** **prior to election** process and post
**paper** **twitter** has been used as a forum to understand the sentiments of

file_2:

social media is the most commonly used **publication** on internet where
people **this case** and **sell** their emotions with **communities** **prepare**
**profound** social media applications and **help** **witness** a **robot which** social
**profoundly** **useful** in the political campaign across **the more resources** have
**four** **serious** political **campaign** **scrap inefficient** process and post
**people** **treated** has been used as a forum to understand the sentiments of

I marked with bold that is word change between two files. 
I want this word difference in file_3 as like below.

application - publication

discuss - this case

share - sell

I have tried with below but its giving line difference

```
import difflib
with open('file_1') as f1:
    f1_text = f1.read()
with open('file_2') as f2:
    f2_text = f2.read()


for line in difflib.unified_diff(f1_text, f2_text, fromfile='file_1', tofile='file_2', lineterm=''):
    print line
```

Python or shell script both are accepted.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: "discuss - this case" yes, for single word is having two words...

Comment: I'd advise you to `split()` `f1_text` and `f2_text` and to compare those.